# Trace a line on canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, touch, html5-canvas

I am learning HTML5 and one of the examples that I want to learn is to create 2 points on a canvas and I should be able to trace a line between the 2 points and join them, this should be done both using mouse and touch events on the mobile devices.

Are there any frameworks that provide these API or are there any examples that I can look at to get started?

Comment: Personally I like to do this without frameworks, but some of the frameworks available include http://raphaeljs.com/ and http://processingjs.org/. You could just combine touch events and calculate where points should be put; then draw a line between them.

Comment: This question is very open ended, and a quick google search would bring you far towards an answer.  There are good tutorials on webgl and canvas out there, also most of the major javascript frameworks will help you out with mobile device support, check out jquery mobile and YUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onload=function(){

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
var mouse={x:0,y:0}, down=false, lines=[]

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e) {
                                    down=true
                                    mouse={x:e.pageX,y:e.pageY}

                },false);

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e) {
                         this.width=this.width
                         lines.map(function(item){
                          ctx.beginPath()
                          ctx.moveTo(item[0].x, item[0].y);
                          ctx.lineTo(item[1].x, item[1].y);
                          ctx.stroke();
                           })
               if(down){
                   ctx.beginPath();
                   ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
                   ctx.lineTo(e.pageX-this.offsetLeft, e.pageY-this.offsetTop);
                   ctx.stroke()
                   }

            },false);

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",function(e) {
                         down=false
                         this.width=this.width
                         lines.push([{x:mouse.x,y:mouse.y},{x:e.pageX-this.offsetLeft,y:e.pageY-this.offsetTop}])
                         lines.map(function(item){
                              ctx.beginPath()
                              ctx.moveTo(item[0].x, item[0].y);
                              ctx.lineTo(item[1].x, item[1].y);
                              ctx.stroke();
                              })
                },false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made up a very basic snippet which might help you get started: http://jsfiddle.net/vF4dY/.

```
var ctx = $('canvas').get(0).getContext('2d');

$('canvas').mousedown(function(e) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
});

$('canvas').mouseup(function(e) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    ctx.stroke();
});
```